# Does Basic "hello world" run as CGI.?

Tags: apache-httpd, cgi

My question is simple.

I install apache on centos and create a file as index.html and just add the content of "hello world".

Now, when I access my web it display the "hello world" quote. My question is does this process run as CGI or Apache-handler or any other API.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a file ending .html is by default just treated as static HTML.